# Cassandra client connection issue within Docker from an application container

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose

```
batchWorker_1  | [DEBUG] 2017-10-30 12:42:10.035 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] Connection - Connection[/172.17.0.3:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Error connecting to /172.17.0.3:9042 (connection timed out: /172.17.0.3:9042)
batchWorker_1  | [DEBUG] 2017-10-30 12:42:10.037 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] STATES - Defuncting Connection[/172.17.0.3:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] because: [/172.17.0.3:9042] Cannot connect
batchWorker_1  | [DEBUG] 2017-10-30 12:42:10.038 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] STATES - [/172.17.0.3:9042] preventing new connections for the next 1000 ms
batchWorker_1  | [DEBUG] 2017-10-30 12:42:10.038 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] STATES - [/172.17.0.3:9042] Connection[/172.17.0.3:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] failed, remaining = 0
batchWorker_1  | [DEBUG] 2017-10-30 12:42:10.039 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] Connection - Connection[/172.17.0.3:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
batchWorker_1  | [DEBUG] 2017-10-30 12:42:10.042 [main] ControlConnection - [Control connection] error on /172.17.0.3:9042 connection, no more host to try
batchWorker_1  | com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/172.17.0.3:9042] Cannot connect
batchWorker_1  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:165) ~[batch_worker_server.jar:0.01]
batchWorker_1  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:148) ~[batch_worker_server.jar:0.01]
...
```

I am running my application and a Cassandra container, trying to establish connection from application container to Cassandra container.

1. I tried with docker-compose. It throws the same error. It is able to resolve the right container IP (as you can see) but failing to connect.
2. I tried to run by starting cassandra container separately and harddcode the IP in my application container, it still fails.
3. The Cassandra container works fine, if i run the same app outside, it connect.

The issue is that, it is not able to resolve the Cassandra container IP from the application container. Not sure why.

I also enabled `start_rpc` and exposed all cassandra related ports. Still no luck.

Comment: What cassandra image are you using. Official (https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) or your own?

Comment: i tried many. I am using the official one.

Comment: This seems like a issue with your application (or how it is run in Docker) and not with Cassandra. Could you show us some output of 'docker container ls'

Answer (score 4):

### Issue

[Control connection] error on /IP:9042 connection, no more host to try

### Solution

> Silly but important check "App tries to connect before cassandra is up"

**RPC_ADDESS Default IP Issue**

As containers have their own network. So every container will takes its own IP. As your RPC_ADDESS is set to container IP it will through this error.

In Cassandra configuration change the IP address of

> **rpc_address**  (Default: localhost) The listen address for client
> connections (Thrift RPC service and native transport).
> Valid values:

1. unset: Resolves the address using the configured hostname

> configuration of the node. If left unset, the hostname resolves to the
> IP address of this node using /etc/hostname, /etc/hosts, or DNS.

2. 0.0.0.0: Listens on all configured interfaces. You must set the broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0.

> 3. IP address
>    4. hostname
>
> RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0

Here is **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '2'
services:  
    cassandra:
        container_name: cassandra
        image: cassandra:3.9
        volumes:
            - /path/of/host/for/cassandra/:/var/lib/cassandra/
        ports:
            - 7000:7000
            - 7001:7001
            - 7199:7199
            - 9042:9042
            - 9160:9160
        environment:
            - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME='cassandra-cluster'
            - CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=256
            - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
        restart: always
```

Comment: I am trying this. I figured the issue though. If i run my container with a pre existing network with `--network preexistingnetwork` and then provide that as default preexisting network in docker-compose with inspected IP, it works, otherwise it doesnt. Basically the networking is not getting resolved when started through compose file for cassandra. Not sure why.

Comment: Is your application and cassandra both in same server? run cassandra with one network, Run your application with external network true

Comment: Yeah, local machine. Just for testing purposes.if you can point me to any service + application docker compose v3 with network example. it would be great

Comment: If docker-compose for cassandra and docker-compose for application both are in same folder. when you create container with compose being in the folder it creates a network with folderName_default, if both compose files in same file folder then both will run under same network. so need to create a external network. if both are on ifferent folders you need to create a network and make it run under that network

Comment: Its a single compose with cassandra and a single application.

Comment: One silly reason i could think of is that, maybe the app tries to connect before cassandra is up and running. (I added links and depends_on, but i think i need to also add healthcheck to make sure client connection is possible.)

Comment: @jarvis11 Could you tell what kind of healthcheck you performed ?

Comment: @Kenairod Yes, I used the healthcheck construct from docker compose and executed a `CMD-SHELL` shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Docker network as [described in documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/), and connect Cassandra & your application to same network.

You also need to check on what interfaces Cassandra is listening - is it single interface, or all?

Comment: rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
# rpc_interface: eth1
# rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6: false

rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 172.22.0.2


This is what I have inside my cassandra.yaml inside the container.

Comment: Even if I create network and add a default external network in my docker-compose file, It still fails to connect. Anything I need to change in my cassandra.yaml? @alex-ott